# windows 8.1 update fails with no reason

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-update

I decided to update Windows 8 to 8.1 over the weekend. However after the 4GB download and the 1 hour install procedure, it reverts back to 8 and gives me a message saying that it could not be done.

(the computer works fine still, but in 8.0)

Is this a known issue? How can i find out what the actual reason is? (event viewer was useless)

**edited to add:**
In this case, the system is a fairly fresh install (2 months and very little use) and has all updates applied. System spec is an i7 920 running stock speed, 2x geforce 260 in SLI, 6GB DDR3.

Comment: upload the log files: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824819.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your system may be changed in the way that updater fails to recognize some parameters needed.
You may use `sfc /scannow` to set your OS to the initial state and try updating, but i would recommend to reinstall it completely instead of updating